# MATLAB - need help plotting highly non-linear function

Tags: matlab, plot, nonlinear-functions

This is the equation that I want to plot in MATLAB -

[image]

I want to sweep the variable V<sub>bi</sub> from `-5` to `+5` and then plot the variable `T` for each individual value of V<sub>bi</sub> (essentially `T` vs. `Vbi`) for `Nd = Na =`10<sup>15</sup>, 10<sup>16</sup> and 10<sup>17</sup>.

I know V<sub>bi</sub> can be swept by creating a vector:

```
Vbi = -5 : 0.001 : 5;
```

But I am not sure how to go about solving this problem, as I have never faced something like 
this before. Can someone please advice on how to code this?

Comment: Have you tried [ezplot](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html)

Comment: In matlab you have so many way to do it. Use member-wise operator such as ./ or parse it within a for loop.

Comment: @RobertP.: euhm...he bothered allright; he wrote the equation down by hand, made a picture of it and uploaded it to imgur and posted the link here, presumably as a workaround for his inability to post pictures. And I think this was the right thing to do, as the implicit equation would only look "friendly" enough when it is typeset rather than written in code. I just took care of the typesetting; correcting your -1 with a +1.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest is to use a loop through all values you want, and use `fzero` to find all values for the non-linear implicit function:

```
% Values for Na/Nd you want
Na = [1e15 1e16 1e17];
Nd = Na;

% Vbi values you want to sweep
VbiValues = -5 : 0.001 : 5;

% Initialize outputs
Tout = zeros(numel(VbiValues), numel(Na));

% Solve equation for each value of Vbi
for ii = 1:numel(VbiValues)
    for jj = 1:numel(Na)

        % Re-define equation for new value of Vbi, Na, Nd
        eq = @(T) -T + 11603.24*VbiValues(ii) ./ log(Na(jj)*Nd(jj)/2.798e39 * 300./T .* exp(13452./T));

        % Solve it
        Tout(ii,jj) = fzero(eq, 10);

    end
end

% plot results
plot(...
    VbiValues, Tout(:,1), 'r', ...
    VbiValues, Tout(:,2), 'g', ...
    VbiValues, Tout(:,3), 'b')
L = legend(...
    '$N_A = N_D = 10^{15}$',... 
    '$N_A = N_D = 10^{16}$',... 
    '$N_A = N_D = 10^{17}$');
set(L, 'Interpreter', 'LaTeX');
```

Alternatively, if you have the optimization toolbox, you can use `fsolve`:

```
function topLevelFunction

    % Values for Na/Nd you want
    Na = [1e15 1e16 1e17];
    Nd = Na;

    % Vbi values you want to sweep
    VbiValues = -5 : 0.01 : 5;

    % Use fsolve() to solve the system in one go
    Tout = fsolve(@(T)F(T, VbiValues, Nd), ones(numel(Nd),numel(VbiValues)));

    % plot results
    plot(...
        VbiValues, Tout(1,:), 'r', ...
        VbiValues, Tout(2,:), 'g', ...
        VbiValues, Tout(3,:), 'b')
    L = legend(...
        '$N_A = N_D = 10^{15}$',...
        '$N_A = N_D = 10^{16}$',...
        '$N_A = N_D = 10^{17}$');
    set(L, 'Interpreter', 'LaTeX');

end

function Fvals = F(Ttrials, Vbis, Nad)

    % Output function values for 
    % - all Vbi   (each column is a different Vbi)
    % - all Na/Nd (each row is a different Na/Nd) 
    Fvals = -Ttrials + bsxfun(@rdivide, ...
        11603.24*Vbis(:).', ...
        log( bsxfun(@times, Nad(:).^2/2.798e39, 300./Ttrials .* exp(13452./Ttrials)) ));

end
```

Note that one of the two solutions (or both :) still contains an error, as the two plots are not the same, but I'm sure this will help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's simple to rearrange the formula to V. Why don't you reformulate and sweep over T?

That way you might also see if there are T for which there is no solution (log of negative vaules or so).

btw if these quantities are physical T (temperature) and V (volume) you might consider not to go over negative values...

*Update*

just did a bit of symbolic maths:

```
syms T V a b c reals
fun = a*V/(log(b/T*exp(c/T)))-T;
r =solve(fun==0,V);
```

and then on notepad:

```
V = (T*log((b*exp(c/T))/T))/a
V = ( T* [log(b) + log(exp(c/T)) -log(T)] )/a
V = ( T* [log(b) + c/T -log(T)] )/a
V = c/a - T/a*log(T/b)
```

at least the relation is monotonic. So the solution will be unique.

Comment: +1 for the outside-the-box-thinking, however, `T` is unknown and `Vbi`  known. Therefore, it is impossible other than by trial and error to find out what the correct range of `T` would be in order to get to the known values of `Vbi`.

Comment: True. I was thinking he'd be free to plot over some limits to T as well. Anyway `fzero` should have an easy time finding T. Might save him some time once he knows the limits.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a recursive function ?  something like this ?
[image]

There is still a little difference between your first formula and the typed version. have (300/T) term an exponent ?